# Where has the "units" sub-module in qiskit_nature gone?

Tags: units-of-measurement, qiskit

I am trying to follow this [qiskit "Electronic Structure" tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.25/tutorials/chemistry/01_electronic_structure.html), but at the very first step, setting up the PySCF driver with the following

```
from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver

driver = PySCFDriver(
    atom="H 0 0 0; H 0 0 0.735",
    basis="sto3g",
    charge=0,
    spin=0,
    unit=DistanceUnit.ANGSTROM,
)
```

produces an error. The error says there is no module "units" in qiskit_nature.

I have installed qiskit_nature with pip (pip3, python 3.6) and when I listed the submodules of qiskit_nature I get

```
algorithms
circuit
constants
converters
deprecation
drivers
exceptions
mappers
operators
problems
properties
results
runtime
settings
transformers
version
```

I checked most and there appears not to be a "units" module anywhere. While the call to the submodule "units" in the above may be trivial and/or circumvented, where has the submodule gone? Is it missing because when they ported the "qiskit.chemistry" to "nature" they re-organised things? If so, why do the tutorials on the "nature" module not reflect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to run the latest tutorial but you do not have the latest version of Qiskit Nature installed. This is based on three observatons:

1. The `units` module is missing which only got added in Qiskit Nature v0.5.0
2. The `second_q` module is missing, too, which also got added in that version.
3. Furthermore, you say that you are using Python 3.6, support which has been removed in version 0.4.0.

Thus, I strongly assume you installed Qiskit Nature v0.3.2 which is the last release that pip should resolve to under that Python version.

Now, how do you go about solving this problem: I strongly suggest that you first switch to a newer Python version. 3.6 has reached its end of life on Dec 23rd, 2021 [1](https://devguide.python.org/versions/).
I suggest you upgrade to Python 3.9 which will be supported into 2025 and has already been "battle-tested" on all platforms.

Once you have upgrade your Python version, you will need to re-install Qiskit Nature:

```
pip3 install --upgrade qiskit-nature
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, although I cannot upgrade to newer python versions (some large legacy code *only ever* works with *that* python version). About time I learnt about python environments, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The module [`units.py`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/blob/main/qiskit_nature/units.py) is there in Qiskit Nature in the root. There is no package/folder/submodule called units. Its a single file.

Comment: Oh Thanks. Do you know why does "from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit" fail? I am asking because if similar calls/imports fail in similar ways, this will fast become an issue.(Also, technically, given every python file is its own module, I wonder if the title is *that* wrong)

Comment: I just checked with nautilus qiskit_nature.__path__ and there is  no "units.py" in there. There is only constants.py, deprecation.py, exceptions.py, __init.py, settings.py and version.py. That's different from the github repo you just linked to.

Answer (score 0):

pip install --upgrade  qiskit_nature

maybe work around it, replace the import statement from qiskit_nature.units import DistanceUnit with qiskit_nature.units._units

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I did. It didn't do much. Then I copied the units.py file in the install directory, which solved the issue for *that* import, but then a few lines later there is an import from a module "second_q" that isn't found. This appears to be a second quantization module, but which one remains the question. There is a second quantization under properties, another under transformers, another under problems. It appears the qiskit_nature installed with pip bears little resemblance to the qiskit_nature git repo linked to by @SteveWood. I just settled on grabbing that repo.

Comment: @Tico: the repo which Steve linked to is the correct one. But between version 0.3.2 (the one you get installed under Python 3.6 as I explained in my answer) and the latest development branch (which is called `main` and is the landing page of that repo) a LOT has changed. You can find a summary of the changes here: https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/release_notes.html

If you _really_ cannot upgrade Python and still would like to use Qiskit Nature, you need to refer to the documentation of the version which you are actually using.

Comment: (I ran out of characters...)

Currently, the website does not contain the documentation of older versions. But you can access it via Github. This is the stable/0.3 branch: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/tree/stable/0.3
You can clone that and then build the docs from there in your terminal as described here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/blob/stable/0.3/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-qiskit-nature

Comment: @mrossinek - thank you. I accepted your answer as *the* answer because it brought to my attention all I needed to be aware of - a short "fix": works on another machine for the time being with newer python version ... etc. Longer term fix, have separate python environments on the same machine, catering for the various projects.